# Übersetzung des Substantivs “academic”

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> **Academics** are often too concerned about unimportant details.

Wie kann man den Satz am besten übersetzen? Die [Übersetzungen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=academic) von "academic" als Substantiv sind *Akademiker*, *Wissenschaftler* und *Universitätslehrkraft*.

*Akademiker* trifft nicht zu, denn damit sind auch diejenigen aufgenommen, die einen Hochschulabschluss haben, deren Arbeit aber nichts zu tun mit dem akademischen Bereich hat.

*Universitätslehrkraft* ist zu spezifisch, denn "academics" können auch diejenigen sein, die zum Beispiel an einem Forschungsinstitut arbeiten.

*Wissenschaftler* kommt nah dran, aber damit sind zum Beispiel Lehrer für die russische Sprache an einer Uni ausgenommen.

Was passt am besten?

Comment: Wenn "Akademiker" nicht passt, steckt die unpassende Wortwahl nicht auch im Wort "academics"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich würde *Akademiker* wählen, denn es gibt Ausdrücke wie "das ist akademisch" (also: das ist zu theoretisch oder haarspalterisch, und beschäftigt sich eher mit uninteressanten Details als praktischen Anwendungen).

Dass unter *Akademiker* auch Leute mit Hochschulabschluss fallen, die nicht mehr im akademischen Bereich arbeiten, halte ich für ein unwichtiges Detail. Sozusagen für akademisch. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Wenn Wissenschaftler nah ran kommt wäre vieleicht Dozent eine gute Übersetzung

Comment: Nein, denn es geht nicht ums Lehren.